# Bootstrapping Craft for PHPUnit on command line

Tags: php, bootstrap-craft

I'm trying to run some commands on a Jenkins server to have PHPUnit execute the tests and report the results.

When I do `require_once 'craft/app/bootstrap.php';` It is giving an error saying: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in craft/app/bootstrap.php on line 105`

I read that you cannot use bootstrap.php in the craft/app folder because you're essentially trying to bootstrap a webapp (and this server isn't a webserver). It was suggested that I use `craft/etc/console/yiic.php` as my bootstrap file for PHPUnit. However, this is throwing errors about CDbConnection and is unable to connect.

Is there any way to bootstrap Craft from a command line to run PHPUnit? I'm unable to get it working without an apache server.

Answer (score 2):

> I read that you cannot use bootstrap.php in the craft/app folder because you're essentially trying to bootstrap a webapp (and this server isn't a webserver).

Not sure where you read that, but that doesn't sound right.

I'm assuming you've got a multi-environment config setup?  If so, then manually set the [`CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT`](https://craftcms.com/docs/php-constants#craft-environment) PHP constant before you load the Craft `bootstrap.php` file to the environment you want Craft to load in the config files.

That will get rid of the `Undefined index: SERVER_NAME` error you're getting as well as should fixed your database connection issue.

Comment: So what about at the top of my phpunit bootstrap file before I call craft's bootstrap file? 

Just literally define a PHP constant? Like `define("CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT", "dev")` ??

Comment: Sounds about right!

Comment: That did resolve the error, now onto the next error in a long list of them to get phpunit working on jenkins -.- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an edge case, but if you're using the Kint logging/dumping extension for Craft in your console command, be careful. I got the undefined index SERVER_NAME error trying to to save an entry and output success/fail:

```
d(craft()->entries->saveEntry($entryModel)); --> SERVER_NAME index error
```

This fixed it:

```
$save_result = craft()->entries->SaveEntry($entryModel);
d($save_result);
```

Hope that saved someone a few minutes.